# Missing site collection Templates and The product key could not be validated. Check the error logs for details

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I just installed a SharePoint 2013 and configured the farm. As I used a server 2012 r2, I downloaded a slipstream version of SharePoint, [found here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42039).

After installed, when creating a site collection, I noticed there was just a few site collection templates. Supposing it was a license problem, since i had not inserted one during installation, i tryed to change it for a enterprise license using Update and Migration link.

There, the license textbox and OK button was disabled, By following the steps of [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2011/01/18/what-can-happen-when-you-try-to-convert-a-standard-sharepoint-2010-farm-to-enterprise.aspx), I filled the textbox with the license key and clicked OK and then the following error message displayed.

> The product key could not be validated. Check the error logs for
>   details.

Lots of search, no solution found here.

Has anyone a solution for it ?

Comment: look this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16033.sharepoint-2013-migrate-from-sharepoint-foundation-2013-to-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

Comment: and this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: The problem was my setup download link. I've downloaded SharePoint Foundation instead of SharePoint Server 2013.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stefano Paterno. He found the source of problem

The problem was my setup download link. I've downloaded SharePoint Foundation instead of SharePoint Server 2013.